# How to render real time integer?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm working with a light sensor.
I want to render this real time number to UI.
Something like a progress bar or seek bar.
The bar should be adjusted automatically according to the changes in number.
Can you give me some guidelines?

Here is the code that gets this real-time number.
Right now I just log in to the console.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    Log.e("lightsensor",String.valueOf(sensorEvent.values[0]));

}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you have an issue, looks like you haven't bothered to read about the [layout editor](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html) or anything at all. Voting to close this.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm a beginner. I looked to changes of imageView or TextView. Thus, I was confused about real time changing whether I need something like LISTENER of the UI or not. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML layout you need to set the element you need, maybe a ProgressBar
https://dzone.com/articles/android-example-progress-bar

```
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progressBar"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="visible"
/>
```

after you have the UI you can set the value using

```
ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.firstBar);
bar.setProgress(sensorEvent.values[0])
```

you might want to read up on the layout system
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html

Comment: Thank you! I  I misunderstood that I need something like listener of the progress bar.